# Adding a static block below product listings

Tags: admin, static-block

I want to add a static block below product listings, this is mainly for SEO purposes, we would prefer to do this in admin if possible as opposed to the back end on the server.

We are retailers NOT experts so layman's terms please.

Comment: Creating a static block is pretty straight forward, but if you want to add it somewhere you'll either have to edit some XML files to include it, or modify template (.phtml) files to call your static block.

Answer (score 2):

Assuiming you know how to create `Static Blocks` so after creating `static blocks` to call them in a respective `.phtml`/`.xml` files

For calling in `.phtml` file use this code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml() ?>
```

and to call them in `.xml` files use this code.

```
<block type="cms/block" name="your_block_name">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>your_block_id</block_id></action>
</block>
```

let me know if you need any extra information about this.